# Can't install wordpress on my VPS: "There has been a critical error on this website."

Tags: wordpress

I have VPS on OVH with Centos 8, php 7.2.24, mysql 8.0.21 I also have free cloudflare ssl where I add DNS for wordpress and I turn on Development Mode in Cache configuration cloudflare. Domain where I want to install wordpress are acitvie and work without problem.
I download latest wordpress edit wp-config.php and go to browser and open /wp-admin/install.php and I got message [image]

I don't know what is worng. I edit wp-config.php end enable DEBUG `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` but still get same message without any error message. I try to enable `display_errors` in php.ini file but it seams to not work. phpinfo() show `Loaded Configuration File  /etc/php.ini` and I edit this file.
How to find what is wrong?

Comment: I am getting same issue on local. I am trying to install wordpress on xamp server, I am getting this issue.